# How do applications sandbox plugins/widgets?

Tags: python, wordpress, plugins, web-applications, architecture

In general terms, is there a particular method that can be used to prevent the author of a plugin/widget from exploiting the app i.e. for malicious use?

For example, WordPress. Does it follow a particular architecture or set of design patterns?

I could enforce that the author gives me the data and I decide how to render it but that would be limiting. Can this be done without significantly limiting developers? Both front end and backend? (JavaScript and python in my case)

I am creating a dashboard where developers can create widgets, so they can write a plugin which consists of a front end widget (anything from a simple list to Google maps) and a back end script which handles wiring such as API requests.

Comment: well, security is a very huge topic to be answered in one question. But since you mentioned wordpress, remember that mainly due to its plugins it has a LOT of vulnerabilities - so I wouldn't say that its 'recipe' is very successful.

Comment: You should use a csrf token.

Comment: Ok, I presumed something as big as WordPress would have it figured out... But taking them as an example, if they had a successful recipe ;)